# Error when running processes in Python with a list as input

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get this code to work:

**CODE**

**Process run method**

```
def process(tetrahedrons, startOfWork, endOfWork, RelativeResult):
print("Start of the process", mp.current_process().name)
result = False
for c in range(startOfWork,endOfWork):
    for j in range(c+1,len(tetrahedrons)):
        if tetrahedrons[c].IsInterpenetrated(tetrahedrons[j]) == 1:
            result = True
print("Relative result = ",result, end="\n\n")
RelativeResult.put(result)
```

**Parallel search method**

```
 @staticmethod   
def parallelInterpenetrationSearchWithProcess(tetrahedrons):
    
    '''
    parallel verification of the existence of an interpenetration between tetrahedra
    '''
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

    N_CORE = mp.cpu_count()
    RelativeResult = mp.Queue()
    Workers = []
    dimList = len(tetrahedrons)
    QuantityForWorker = int(dimList / N_CORE)
    Rest = dimList % N_CORE
    StartWork = 0
    if QuantityForWorker == 0:
        iterations = Rest -1
    else:
        iterations = N_CORE
    for i in range(iterations):
        EndWork = StartWork + QuantityForWorker
        if i < Rest -1:
            EndWork = EndWork + 1
        IdWork = i
        Workers.append(mp.Process(target= process, args=(tetrahedrons, StartWork, EndWork, RelativeResult,)))
        Workers[IdWork].start()
        StartWork = EndWork
    for worker in Workers:
            worker.join()

    while not(RelativeResult.empty()):
        if RelativeResult.get():
            print("Parallel search took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))
            return True
    print("Parallel search took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))
    return False
```

*What this code does:* the static method of parallel search takes as input a list of "tetrahedron" objects, and checks if a certain property is verified between these elements, which case would be the search for an intersection between the two tetrahedra.

The parallel search method is called by a main method which builds the list of tetrahedra and then passes it to the parallel search method to verify the above property.
I tried to test this code with a tetrahedron list containing 100 elements and it works fine but when I try to run it with a higher input, "specifically 160000 elements", I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

So I thought that the problem could lie in the use of the current parameters, since going to pass a list containing 160000 elements to a process, the latter would copy this list in memory, and carrying out this procedure for 4 or 8 processes, would not have been the maximum. Convinced of this solution then I had done in such a way as to pass a part of the list and only one element to be checked to each process, but this approach also gave negative results. So I tried to share the list between processes with the help of multiprocessing.Manager (). Exactly:

```
    @staticmethod   
def parallelInterpenetrationSearchWithProcess(tetrahedrons):
    
    '''
    parallel verification of the existence of an interpenetration between tetrahedra
    '''
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

    N_CORE = mp.cpu_count()
    RelativeResult = mp.Queue()
    Workers = []
    trList = mp.Manager().list(tetrahedrons)
    dimList = len(tetrahedrons)
    QuantityForWorker = int(dimList / N_CORE)
    Rest = dimList % N_CORE
    StartWork = 0
    if QuantityForWorker == 0:
        iterations = Rest -1
    else:
        iterations = N_CORE
    for i in range(iterations):
        EndWork = StartWork + QuantityForWorker
        if i < Rest -1:
            EndWork = EndWork + 1
        IdWork = i
        Workers.append(mp.Process(target= process, args=(trList, StartWork, EndWork, RelativeResult,)))
        Workers[IdWork].start()
        StartWork = EndWork
    for worker in Workers:
            worker.join()

    while not(RelativeResult.empty()):
        if RelativeResult.get():
            print("Parallel search took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))
            return True
    print("Parallel search took %f seconds" % ( timeelapsed(time_start) ))
    return False
```

But this approach gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\85612\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\85612\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\85612\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file     
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\85612\Documents\GMarco2\tet\main.py", line 19, in <module>
    out = mesh.mesh.parallelInterpenetrationSearchWithProcess(trList)
  File "c:\Users\85612\Documents\GMarco2\tet\mesh\mesh.py", line 264, in parallelInterpenetrationSearchWithProcess
    trList = mp.Manager().list(tetrahedrons)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 701, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 586, in _create
    id, exposed = dispatch(conn, None, 'create', (typeid,)+args, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 78, in dispatch
    c.send((id, methodname, args, kwds))
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\85612\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

In the first case with the error: **EOFError: Ran out of input** it seems as if trying to read from file. I don't know if this message is due to Python being an interpreted language or not. I have read a lot of questions about it with different solutions but none that could help me. However, I have noticed that **Pickle** is mentioned in many of these solutions. *From what I understand Pickle is essentially concerned with converting a hierarchy of Python objects into a stream of bytes*. I'm new to python and all this information is creating a bit of confusion.

**Question**

In conclusion I would like to know what my problem could be, if I am wrong in something or if I am missing some piece of the puzzle to be able to make my code work. A brief explanation of the role Pickle plays in my code would also be welcome if possible. Thanks in advance.

Looking through the online documentation on pickle I noticed that this module is [used in multiprocessing information passing](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=898687156&utm_adgroupid=48947256715&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=332602034349&utm_targetid=aud-299261629574:dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1008727&gclid=CjwKCAiAiML-BRAAEiwAuWVggklgRAooQHF9cJNVp7X0XeivrAcYxTvgkKKe1kHwDCIs3aIjPbtoghoCm1oQAvD_BwE#multiprocessing).
So the doubt I have is that my classes are badly managed by pickle or rather that [they cannot be pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). I am trying to verify that this statement is true, but I am having quite a few difficulties in making my code digestible to pickle.

**This is my tetrahedron class**

```
    def handedness(vertices):
    """
    returns the handedness of a list of vertices
    """
    # compute handedness
    c = np.cross(vertices[1].coords-vertices[0].coords , vertices[2].coords-vertices[0].coords)
    h = np.inner( c, vertices[3].coords-vertices[0].coords )
    return h

class tetrahedron:
    """
    a tetrahedron
    """
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        """
        initialize a tetrahedron
        """
        # compute handedness
        h = handedness(vertices)

        # vertex indices with correct right-handed orientation
        if h > 0:
            self.vertices = vertices
        else:
            s = "old h = %f" % (h)
            # swap last two vertices
            self.vertices = [vertices[0], vertices[1], vertices[3], vertices[2]]
            vertices = self.vertices
            h = handedness(vertices)
            s = s + " new h = %f" % (h)
            print(s)
```

**This is my vertex class**

```
class vertex:
"""
a vertex
"""

def __init__(self, coords, idx):
    """
    initialize a vertex
    """
    
    # vertex coordinates
    self.coords = numpy.array(coords)

    # incident triangles
    self.triangles = []
    # id
    self.idx = idx
```

Comment: seems likes you've reached the maximum complexity for pickling an item, this shouldn't happen in any normal data structure (as the maximum in the latest x86 python should be in the thousands) if your data really is that complex you can try changing the recursion limit but that might not work if you need a recursion depth that is too big

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Consider that we are talking about a list of tetrahedra, where each tetrahedron is composed of 4 vertices, each of which is composed of a list of coordinates [x, y, z].

Comment: that;s 1497 too few recursions to cause a problem